# $ax\equiv ay \pmod {n}$ if and only if $x\equiv y \pmod{n/(a,n)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$ax\equiv ay \pmod {n}$ if and only if $\displaystyle x\equiv y \pmod{n/(a,n)}$

I have found this proof

If $ax\equiv ay \pmod {n}$, then $ax-ay=mz$, for some $z \in \mathbb{Z}$. So

$\displaystyle \frac{a}{(a,n)}(x-y)=\frac{n}{(a,n)}z $

Thus,

$\displaystyle \frac{n}{(a,n)} \Biggm| \frac{a}{(a,n)}(x-y) $

But $\left ( \frac{n}{(a,n)}, \frac{a}{(a,n)} \right )=1$, then $\frac{n}{(a,n)}\Bigm|(x-y)$ and therefore $\displaystyle x\equiv y \pmod{n/(a,n)}$.

On the other hand, if $\displaystyle x\equiv y \pmod{n/(a,n)}$, then $\frac{n}{(a,n)}\Bigm|(x-y)$. So $n\mid(a,n)(x-y)$. Then $n\mid a(x-y)$ and therefore $ax\equiv ay \pmod {n}$

My problem is with this last part, what is the argument that allows me to conclude that if $n\mid(a,n)(x-y)$, then $n\mid a(x-y)$?

Comment: Because $(a,n)$ is a divisor of $a$.

Comment: If $n\mid b$ then $n\mid kb$

Comment: $n|(a,n)(x-y)$ and $(a,n)(x-y)|a(x-y)$ so $n|a(x-y)$ by transitivity of divisibility.

Comment: For some $z\in \mathbb Z$,

$$x-y = \frac{n}{(a,n)}z \implies a(x-y) = n\cdot\frac{a}{(a,n)}z$$